# CUDA issue - how to clean install CUDA in Win 10 to resolve cudaGetDevice() failed

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, cuda

I have previously had CUDA 9.x running on this Win 10 64-bit Home system (targeting 1080Ti card), but need to update to CUDA 10.0 for TensorFlow 2. I initially thought TF2 was OK with CUDA 10.1 and so first installed 10.1 and only later found out that it must be CUDA 10.

Can't get it to work...

To test TF, I ran this to validate the installation(Jupyter notebook via Anaconda - freshly built TF2 environment)

```
import tensforflow as tf
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
```

I get this error in the basic Python test

> InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found

This suggests that a key file cannot be found, but I can't work out the root cause - and there are very few hits on that error info, none of which helped me.

**Current Config**

CUDA 10.0 installed
Nvidia driver 436.48 game ready driver

**Potential issues & resolution actions so far**

Obviously none of them have fixed things

1. Old CUDA installations - 9.0, 9.1, 10.0, 10.1: all except 10.0 uninstalled and PC rebooted; 10.0 installer then run again
2. Updating cudnn files: tried 1st with the originals and then cudnn files v7.6.3.30 copied to bin, include, lib as appropriate
3. Switch from game ready driver to "Studio" driver
4. Check all environment variables - removed everything that referred to CUDA != 10.0
5. **Update** renamed nvcuda.dll to .old in system32 and reran the CUDA 10.0 installer... a new nvcuda was *not* produced.
6. **Update 2** I found nvcuda64.dll v 10.0.132 in the driver store and replaced nvcuda.dll in system32 with it; after reboot, nvidia-smi now reports no CUDA version at all :(

**Known Oddities**

1. **[superseded by Update 2]** nvidia-smi.exe reports CUDA 10.1 (yes, it is available on my Win 10) - but checking through the registry I can't find anything to suggest CUDA 10.1 is lingering there...**Update** Found it in C:\Windows\System32
2. Despite uninstalls, I still have CudaXYZWizardsPackage in the registry under the key Computer\HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\InstalledProducts with XYZ = 90, 91, 100, 101 - but I doubt this is the issue for TF in Python ;) **Update** there is nothing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\NVIDIA except for 10.0 so just orphan reg entries.

**Other info**

1. Before doing all the uninstalls etc. I did successfully build and run the Nvidia sample clock project in VS 2017 so the basics were OK (then)

**Questions**

1. How can I completely remove all trace of CUDA to start again from a clean slate?
2. How could I diagnose such issues in future to work out where the issue is/what to do
3. Can this particular issue be resolved more simply?
4. (New) Where can I get nvcuda.dll 10.0 to replace in system32? - **Answer** one possibility is from C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository

Comment: A downvote?? "This q is does not show effort, is not clear etc.?" That downvote is more susceptible to that assessment than the Q  because there is no explanation, no advice on how to improve it, etc.. I am always open to +ve contributions on how to improve things... please advise

Comment: "nvidia-smi.exe reports CUDA 10.1" -- that is only the driver compatibility, it doesn't say anything about what you have installed. My opinion is that is either a tensorflow setup question, or it is off-topic. You should tag and edit it accordingly

Comment: @talonmies Whilst the ultimate goal is TF setup, the question is specifically: how to remove all trace of a CUDA installation to start afresh + intimately connected items. I shall amend the title accordingly.

Comment: Keep us posted of anything new you find. Apparently there is a very sensitive combination of versions of cuda, tf, python, gpu, and gpu driver to make this work. Very annoying.

Comment: @Diego I am aware of the very complex dependencies... what's hard is to find consistent sets described in one place. I am going to rebuild Windows (new HDD temporarily) and start from scratch. Very painful. Also nVidia full remove instructions with ?Revo uninstaller are not full enough and a) remove uninstall info for remaining NVidia apps etc. unless one is careful and b) still leave an impossible-to-manage collecting of reg entries behind. I couldn't even manage to "properly" remove the nv graphics driver for a plain VGA version. Very, very, very annoying

Answer (score 2):

1. download and install Anaconda (Python 3.7): https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/
2. in Command Prompt:

```
conda update conda
conda update python

conda create --name tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tensorflow-gpu
conda install pip jupyter
pip install tensorflow-gpu
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

3. in Start menu select `Anaconda3 (64-bit) -> Jupyter Notebook (tensorflow-gpu)`

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

```
%%time
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    a = tf.random.uniform([1000,1000])
    b = tf.random.uniform([1000,1000])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

> Wall time: 18.9 ms

```
%%time
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    a = tf.random.uniform([1000,1000])
    b = tf.random.uniform([1000,1000])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

> Wall time: 2.99 ms

Comment: The OS is windows, and whilst, according to this page https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip, there is support for Python 3.7 under Linux, it is notably absent from the Windows information. The steps you described were already performed; it is in executing e.g. tf.random.uniform([1000,1000]) that the issue appears. When the evidence seems to be strongly in favour of a CUDA issue (i.e. 10.1 CUDA driver when 10.1 was uninstalled and 10.0 installed) , can you offer some compelling reason for reinstalling python?

Comment: @JulianMoore I have Windows 10 (1903), CUDA 10.1, cuDNN 7.6. MXNet can see CUDA 10.1. But TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch can only work with CUDA 10.0. The main trick in my answer is: `conda install cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch`. Therefore, I do not need to remove CUDA 10.1. And yes, TensorFlow 2.0 works with Python 3.7 on Windows.

Comment: I shall try that tomorrow - thanks. What does the -c pytorch trick do?

Comment: Download from PyTorch repository.

Comment: 1st test (matmul) failed with error "The procedure entry point fatBinaryCtl could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\nvcuda.dll" (which just happens to be the same error as my own previous TF2 installation) What do you suggest?

Comment: I can suggest you reinstall Windows. Instruction from my answer works on 3 different computers. All with Windows 10 (1903), CUDA 10.1. But different GPUs: 940MX, GTX1050Ti, RTX2060.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly an extended comment, since @diego ask for updates...

I now CUDA 10.0 installed and the nVidia control panel reports nvcuda.dll as v 10.0.132

I have built the recommended demo devicequery.exe using Visual Studio 2017 from the vs solution in C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v10.0\1_Utilities\deviceQuery (note that the .exe ends up in C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v10.0\bin\win64\Debug)

The program then ran from a cmd prompt and gave the following output.

> devicequery Starting...
>
> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
>
> Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"   CUDA Driver Version / Runtime
>   Version          10.0 / 10.0   CUDA Capability Major/Minor version
>   number:    6.1   Total amount of global memory:                 11264
>   MBytes (11811160064 bytes)   (28) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA
>   Cores/MP:     3584 CUDA Cores   GPU Max Clock rate:
>   1607 MHz (1.61 GHz)   Memory Clock rate:
>   5505 Mhz   Memory Bus Width:                              352-bit   L2
>   Cache Size:                                 2883584 bytes   Maximum
>   Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072,
>   65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)   Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size,
>   (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers   Maximum Layered 2D Texture
>   Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers   Total amount of
>   constant memory:               65536 bytes   Total amount of shared
>   memory per block:       49152 bytes   Total number of registers
>   available per block: 65536   Warp size:
>   32   Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048   Maximum
>   number of threads per block:           1024   Max dimension size of a
>   thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)   Max dimension size of a grid
>   size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)   Maximum memory pitch:
>   2147483647 bytes   Texture alignment:                             512
>   bytes   Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy
>   engine(s)   Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
>   Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No   Support host
>   page-locked memory mapping:       Yes   Alignment requirement for
>   Surfaces:            Yes   Device has ECC support:
>   Disabled   CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM
>   (Windows Display Driver Model)   Device supports Unified Addressing
>   (UVA):      Yes   Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
>   Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No   Supports
>   MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No   Device PCI Domain ID / Bus
>   ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0   Compute Mode:
>        < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
>
> deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.0, CUDA
>   Runtime Version = 10.0, NumDevs = 1 Result = PASS

What did I do to achieve this? Hard to be specific because I didn't realise I had succeeded, but I recall setting the display driver to VGA, rebooting (twice for safety) then uninstalling CUDA 10.0, rebooting then installing 10.0.

I did just notice that I built deviceQuery with a vs 2012 solution, but I did agree to VS updating on solution open.